# jQuery expanding menu bug

Tags: jquery, navigation, toggle, jquery-animate

I've coded a navigation menu which has nested dropdowns within - I've coded the menus to slide down on hover and that's working fine.

However there is also a 'show all' link which when clicked expands all the sub-menus and applies a new class to the container to pad the menus out.

Clicking expands the menu fine but then clicking a second time alters the appearance as it should for a split second by removing the class as if its triggering the function again. My code is below - any help would be greatly appreciated! Andy

```
// == MENU SHOW ALL TOGGLE
// show pointer
$('#menu li#show-all').hover(function(){
    $(this).css({'cursor' : 'pointer'});
});
$('#menu-container').addClass('show-single');

function toggleheight(){
    if ($('#menu-container').hasClass('show-single')) {
        $('#menu li').not('#show-all').fadeOut(function(){

            $('#menu').animate({
                height : '300px'
            }, function(){
                $('#menu-container').removeClass('show-single').addClass('show-all');
                $('#menu li').not('#show-all').fadeIn();
            });
        });
    }else {
        $('#menu li').not('#show-all').fadeOut(function(){
            $('#menu-container').removeClass('show-all').addClass('show-single');
            $('#menu').animate({
                height : '16px'
            }, function(){
                $('#menu li').not('#show-all').fadeIn();
            });

        });
    }
}

$('#menu li#show-all').click(function(){
        $(toggleheight);
});
```

EDIT : expanding the menu, hovering a link then moving back and clicking the show all link does revert the menu as it should - however clicking the 'show all' link once to expand the once more to shrink without navigating away seems to re-trigger the functions

Answer (score 1):

I decided not to dig into your code and try to fix it because I think there's a much better approach to building navigation menus, with a simple jQuery plugin. However, this doesn't really help you solve your problem with your code, but hopefully you'll find this useful anyways.

So, here's what I came up with.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="nav-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Subsubmenu 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Subsubmenu 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Subsubmenu 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Subsubmenu 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Plugin code:**

```
(function($){

    function traverseItems($items) {
        $items.each(function(){
            var $item = $(this),
                $submenu = $item.children("ul").hide();
            if ($submenu.length) {
                $item.children("a").click(function(){
                    $submenu.toggle();
                    return false;
                }).append(" \>");
                traverseItems($submenu.children("li"));
            }
        });
    }

    $.fn.navMenu = function (options){
        var defaults = {
            showAllToggle: true
        };
        options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        return this.each(function(){
            var $this = $(this)
                    .addClass("nav-menu"),
                $items = $this.children("li");

            traverseItems($items);

            if (options.showAllToggle) {
                $showAll = $("<a></a>")
                    .attr("href", "#")
                    .addClass("show-all")
                    .text("Toggle all")
                    .toggle(function(){
                        $this.find("ul").show();
                        return false;
                    }, function(){
                        $this.find("ul").hide();
                        return false;
                    })
                    .wrap("<li></li>")
                    .parent()
                    .prependTo($this);
            }
        });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

**Usage:**

```
$(function(){
    $(".nav-menu").navMenu();
});
```

You can see it all in action on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/XR4Wt/).

I can elaborate on this answer and cut it down into pieces if requested. If anyone have any suggestions or ideas on how this can be improved, I'm all ears.

Comment: @tbwcf, if you can throw together a test case on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your code that would help alot. I would still recommend you using a jQuery plugin for this.

Comment: Thanks Marcus, I've put a mock-up on jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tbwcf/EKLJx/ - any further help would be appreciated :)